# Como deixar banner na altura correta

Tags: css

Estou tentando sem sucesso deixar um banner com uma altura menor, já inspecionei o código e creio ter achado o código para alteração, coloquei no corpo da página esse código:

```
 
element.style {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 417px;
    width: 1903px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Mas mesmo assim o altura continua a mesma mas não estou conseguindo resolver.
O site pode ser visto aqui:

[Site](https://bonsaicenter.com.br/bonsai/)

Comment: Pq `element.style`? Deveria colocar o id do elemento, classe, tag...

Comment: Então, justamente por isso que postei a pergunta, não sei exatamente como corrigir.

Comment: Mas vc nem falou que banner é esse. Só colocou um link pro seu site, o que por si só já é ruim. Acho que a sua pergunta carece de maiores detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `<head>` do código HTML da sua página você adicionou

```
<style> 
        element.style {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            overflow: visible;
            height: 417px;
            width: 1920px;
            left: 0px;
        }       
</style>
```

Element.style concerne à estilização CSS feita através de JavaScript, então declarar element.style diretamente em seu código css não funcionará na absoluta maioria dos casos.

Para consertar, tudo o que você precisa efetuar é trocar element.style para os seletores adequados, como `div#id1`. O que imagino que você quer fazer é reduzir ou eliminar o slider vermelho ocupando a página.

### Para reduzir:

```
<style>
        section.sec-slider{
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            overflow: visible;
            height: 417px;
            width: 1920px;
            left: 0px;
        }       
</style>
```

Isso aplica o seu estilo apresentado na pergunta com os seletores corretos, o que quebra o site visualmente.

### Para eliminar

```
<style> 
    section.sec-slider{
        display:none
    }       
</style>
```